# Read single large file containing multiple XML files into multiple xml records in C#

Tags: c#

I have a single file that effectively contains multiple XML files of the same format, so the file is not itself valid XML; for instance:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Proposal xmlns="a namespace">
    <ASubnode>Text</ASubNode>
    <LotsOfOtherNodes />
</Proposal>
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Proposal xmlns="a namespace">
    <ASubnode>Text</ASubNode>
    <LotsOfOtherNodes />
</Proposal>
....
```

I would like to process all the Proposal nodes, one at a time; for example:

```
foreach (var proposal in file)
    do something
```

I cannot use XmlReader because it throws an exception upon reaching the intermediate XML declaration nodes. I could possibly read the entire file into a string and then use the Split method, but these files are Gigabytes in size, so that is not particularly attractive as an option. It might seem that I could read the file a line at a time, searching for the appropriate nodes via a regular expression, but the files are not line-formatted as above with one node per line, but rather contain very long lines of multiple nodes, and random line breaks in node text.

Is there a method of achieving this without hand-crafting a text parser?

Comment: ReadAllText, Split, Serialize

Comment: You could use `String.IndexOf` and "jump" from one endnode to the next, processing the text in between.

Comment: Do the xml declarations start from new lines, or they can start at same lines either?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the text line by line without actually parsing the xml, since the header of an xml document is the same:

```
IEnumerable<XDocument> GetDocuments(Stream bulkStream)
{
    var reader = new StreamReader(bulkStream);
    var sb = new StringBuilder();   
    var firstLine = reader.ReadLine();
    string line = firstLine;    
    while(line != null)
    {
        sb.Clear();
        sb.Append(firstLine);
        while((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null && line != firstLine)
        {
            sb.Append(line);
        }

        yield return XDocument.Parse(sb.ToString());
    }
}
```

UPDATE:
Following will work even if the declarations can start in-between of a line:

```
IEnumerable<XDocument> GetDocuments(Stream bulkStream)
{
    const string decl = @"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>";
    var sb = new StringBuilder();   

    bool start = true;
    foreach(var line in GetLines(bulkStream).Where(l => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(l)))
    {
        if (start)
        {
            if (line == decl)
                start = false;
            sb.AppendLine(line);
        }
        else
        {
            if (line == decl)
            {
                sb.ToString().Dump();
                yield return XDocument.Parse(sb.ToString());

                sb.Clear();
                start = true;
                sb.AppendLine(line);
            }
            else
                sb.AppendLine(line);
        }
    }

    sb.ToString().Dump();
    yield return XDocument.Parse(sb.ToString());
}

IEnumerable<string> GetLines(Stream bulkStream)
{
    const string decl = @"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>";
    var reader = new StreamReader(bulkStream);
    string line;
    while((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (line.Contains(decl))
        {
            var declIndex = line.IndexOf(decl);
            yield return line.Substring(0, declIndex);
            yield return decl;
            yield return line.Substring(declIndex + decl.Length);
        }
        else
        {
            yield return line;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This parses your input if you fix errors: ASubnode - ASubNode

Comment: This almost works. Unfortunately the XML declarations do not always lie on a line by themselves; for instance, some lines look like the following:

Comment: Then you could extend this approach to split the line if it contains xml declaration, and append to the previous string builder or the next as appropriate. I hope the xml declarations themselves are not split :)

Comment: I couldn't finish the previous comment because opening the multi-gigabyte file in an editor killed my machine!!
This method almost works. unfortunately the XML declarations do not always lie on a line by themselves; for instance, some lines look like the following:

    ...
    </Proposal><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Proposal xmlns="..."><ApplicationHeader><Description>...

so comparing lines for the XML declaration does not always work.

Comment: Your updated version worked perfectly, thanks. The only problem I found was that some of the declarations in the file used single quotes:
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
and some used double quotes:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 causing the declaration string to sometimes not match, resulting in invalid XML. I think I can alter the code to handle that though.

Comment: Note that you can accept the answer you think it worked for you.

Comment: One slight change to the code is that the start = true; item in
    sb.Clear();
    start = true;
    sb.AppendLine(line);

should be commented out. If you leave it in then when the next GetLine is not the declaration, so the loop stays in the Start state, resulting in a Declaration being added to the end of the string when another declaration is encountered, so you get a declaration at the start and end. Removing this line resulted in the code working perfectly on a file several gigabytes in size.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

1. Tell the XmlReader to not be so picky. Set the [XmlReaderSettings.ConformanceLevel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreadersettings.conformancelevel(v=vs.110).aspx) to ConformanceLevel.Fragment. This will let the parser ignore the fact that there is no root node.

   ```
   var settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
   settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;
   using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(textReader, settings))
   {
        ...
   }
   ```
2. Wrap your XML file with your 'root' element, this way your document will have only one root node

> ```
>  <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
>  <root>
>      <Proposal xmlns="a namespace">
>          <ASubnode>Text</ASubNode>
>          <LotsOfOtherNodes />
>      </Proposal>
>      <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
>      <Proposal xmlns="a namespace">
>          <ASubnode>Text</ASubNode>
>          <LotsOfOtherNodes />
>      </Proposal>
>  ....
>  </root>
> ```

Comment: Regarding your second suggestion: Does that even work with those `<?xml version ... ?>` nodes? Just tested it in Linqpad with `XDocument` and I get `Unexpected XML declaration [...]`.

Comment: @germi, I did not realized that each node has own <?xml version ... ?>. In this case what can be done is those nodes can be removed before wrapping in <root> element, or use option 1.

Comment: Removing the XML declarations is the obvious thing to do. Unfortunately that would require reading in the entire file and handling it as a string. These files are several gigabytes in size so that is not very practical. I suppose I could read the file in chunks, parsing the input and writing a new temporary file out as I go, but that requires writing a parser. Identifying the XML declarations is not straightforward because they do not necessarily lie on a line by themselves.

Comment: You can try option 1 then.

Comment: I tried option 1, but it still does not like the multiple XML declarations.

Comment: Option 1 does not work.  As soon as my reader transversus past the first doc it throws a `Unexpected XML declaration. The XML declaration must be the first node in the document, and no whitespace characters are allowed to appear before it`.  I might try the second option.  I'm finding George's suggestion to be risky